# Left Cancellation Law Fails in a Group?

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to understand group theory by myself and got a bit confused along the way. I'm trying to understand why this doesn't contradict the left cancellation law for groups.

Say I'm working in $Z_{25}$  under multiplication

$a*x=a*y$

***Then***

$15*15=15*5$ $(modulo$ $25)$

$225=75$ $(modulo$ $25)$

$0=0$ $(modulo$ $25)$

***Though***

$15\ne5$

How do I make sense of this, how does this not contradict the left cancellation law?

Is this because 
$15*15=15*5$ $(modulo$ $25)$ can be written in someway to make $x and y$ equal?
$5*(3*15)=5*(3*5)$ $(modulo$ $25)$
$3*(5*15)=5*(3*5)$ $(modulo$ $25)$

EDIT: Okay not gonna lie I have absolutely no idea why this is failing..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because multiplication modulo 25 is not a group! Modular addition always forms a group, but multiplication (without zero) does not unless it is modulo a prime. It does form a group if we restrict to elements that are relatively prime to the modulus.

Comment: I dont understand what group axiom fails? I guess because 5 and 15 for example dont have inverses?

Comment: @Temirzhan Yep, you're right, that's why. Modular addition and multiplication together form what's called a ring, which is like a field except that nonzero elements need not necessarily have multiplicative inverses.

Answer (score 2):

To piggyback on what spaceisdarkgreen is saying, consider first that when you're doing multiplication on group elements, you immediately lose some elements to keep a group structure. This is what is so useful about the Euler Totient Function - it tells us how many elements are in the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$, we write this as $(\mathbb{Z}_{25})^\times$ or sometimes written as $U(25)$ meaning the group of *units* $\bmod 25$, or the invertible elements. (Spoiler alert! There is no number you can multiply $0,5,10,15$ or $20$ by to get $1 \bmod 25$)

Euler's Totient Function tells you there are $\varphi(25) = 5(5-1) = 20$ elements in $U(25)$. Specifically, these will be the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_{25}$ which are *relatively prime* to $25$.

This is why 5 and 15 are giving you troubles. You should also have issues with 0, 10, and 20. Hence if we remove these 5 elements, we'll have $20$ elements and they make up the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}_{25})^\times$ :)